# Как в УНФ добавить поле ОГРН для контрагента в договоре?

Tags: 1с

Подскажите, почему при редактировании шаблонов в 1С "Управление нашей фирмой" нельзя в договор добавить поле ОГРН контрагента - его попросту нет в списке. Есть только ОРГН своей организации.

Comment: Проверьте Справочник.Контрагенты

Comment: см реквизит "Регистрационный номер"